# Why footer isn't sticking with bottom?after reducing the width of the window?

Tags: html, css, footer

Why footer isn't sticking with bottom after reducing the width of the window?

```
<footer>
copyright
</footer>
```

Code: https://codepen.io/FilipoV/pen/rNjgOoW

Comment: if you want the sticker to be always shown at the very bottom of the window, on top of the rest of the content, what you're looking for is position:fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that it get's some space under the footer after reducing window and then scrolling, a fix is:

```
body {
min-height: 100vh;}
```